# NetFileEnum (API) always returns 5

Tags: vb.net, winapi

I'm on the way to create an app, that catches changes in files (with FileSystemWatcher()) and then want to get the user, that has a specific file open (**not** the **owner** of the file).
I have found code for c# and translated it to vb.net.
**Problem: The code compiles, but NetFileEnum always returns 5 (instead of 0).**
I have not really experience with API functions, so maybe I do something wrong with the implementation.
**Thanks for any answer.**
**My code:**

**Call:**

```
dim cUsername = GetUsernameHandlingFile(<FileWithPath>)  
'<FileWithPath> = E.g. M:\temp\abc.xls (whereby M:\ is a network drive)
```

**Functions:**

```
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

Module FileOffenDurch
  <DllImport("Netapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
  Private Function NetApiBufferFree(ByVal Buffer As IntPtr) As Integer
  End Function
  <StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, CharSet:=CharSet.Auto, Pack:=4)>
    Structure FILE_INFO_3
      Public fi3_id As Integer
      Public fi3_permission As Integer
      Public fi3_num_locks As Integer
      Public fi3_pathname As String
      Public fi3_username As String
    End Structure


  <DllImport("netapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
  Private Function NetFileEnum(ByVal servername As String, ByVal basepath As String, ByVal username As String, ByVal level As Integer, ByRef bufptr As IntPtr, ByVal prefmaxlen As Integer, <Out> ByRef entriesread As Integer, <Out> ByRef totalentries As Integer, ByVal resume_handle As IntPtr) As Integer
  End Function

  <DllImport("netapi32.dll", SetLastError:=True, CharSet:=CharSet.Unicode)>
  Private Function NetFileGetInfo(ByVal servername As String, ByVal fileid As Integer, ByVal level As Integer, ByRef bufptr As IntPtr) As Integer
  End Function

  Public Function GetFileIdFromPath(ByVal filePath As String) As Integer
    Const MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH As Integer = -1
    Dim dwReadEntries As Integer
    Dim dwTotalEntries As Integer
    Dim pBuffer As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
    Dim pCurrent As FILE_INFO_3 = New FILE_INFO_3()
    Dim dwStatus As Integer = NetFileEnum(Nothing, filePath, Nothing, 3, pBuffer, MAX_PREFERRED_LENGTH, dwReadEntries, dwTotalEntries, IntPtr.Zero)
    ' => dwStatus always returns 5 (instead of 0)

    If dwStatus = 0 Then
      For dwIndex As Integer = 0 To dwReadEntries - 1
        Dim iPtr As IntPtr = New IntPtr(pBuffer.ToInt32() + (dwIndex * Marshal.SizeOf(pCurrent)))
        pCurrent = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(iPtr, GetType(FILE_INFO_3)), FILE_INFO_3)
        Dim fileId As Integer = pCurrent.fi3_id
        NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer)
        Return fileId
      Next
    End If

    NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer)
    Return -1
  End Function

  Public Function GetUsernameHandlingFile(ByVal fileId As Integer) As String
      Dim defaultValue As String = "[Unknown User]"

      If fileId = -1 Then
        Return defaultValue
      End If

      Dim pBuffer_Info As IntPtr = IntPtr.Zero
      Dim dwStatus_Info As Integer = NetFileGetInfo(Nothing, fileId, 3, pBuffer_Info)

      If dwStatus_Info = 0 Then
        Dim iPtr_Info As IntPtr = New IntPtr(pBuffer_Info.ToInt32())
        Dim pCurrent_Info As FILE_INFO_3 = CType(Marshal.PtrToStructure(iPtr_Info, GetType(FILE_INFO_3)), FILE_INFO_3)
        NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer_Info)
        Return pCurrent_Info.fi3_username
      End If

      NetApiBufferFree(pBuffer_Info)
      Return defaultValue
    End Function

    Public Function GetUsernameHandlingFile(ByVal filePath As String) As String
      Dim fileId As Integer = GetFileIdFromPath(filePath)
      ' Always returns -1 
      Return GetUsernameHandlingFile(fileId)
    End Function
  
End Module
```

Comment: "Access denied", nothing unusual for a network function of course.  Ask IT staff to help you out.

Comment: NetFileEnum always returns 5. The error is `ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED`: The user does not have access to the requested information. Make sure you have permission to access it.

Comment: Thanks to Hans Passant and Jeaninez for the comments. I have not found any description to the return codes to NetFileEnum on the web (not known, that 5 means "access denied"), can you provide a link with all error codes please?
I now know where to search and will check out the rights...

Comment: @FredyWenger The return value of the NetFileEnum function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netfileenum#return-value and 
[System Error Codes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/system-error-codes--0-499-)

Comment: @Jeaninez-MSFT Thanks. The missing link was last "System Error Codes" (link between the code and the meaning). In the meantime, I have done tests with the rights, but nothing works (the function always returns 5). I already had local admin rights (before posting this) and now added "Domain admin" and also "Network Configuration Operators" to my account -> no change:-(. Do you have any idea, what rights exactly are needed?

Comment: Could you maybe update your question with a little more context for the method you're calling this?  Perhaps the reason for your ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED is actually a little further up the chain.  When processing files using the FileSystemWatcher you really need to be aware that it's not uncommon for the events to fire before file handles etc are released so this may just be a simple issue around timings

Comment: You can look up system error codes using the net.exe program. In a command prompt `net helpmsg 5`. *Only members of the Administrators or Server Operators local group can successfully execute the NetFileGetInfo function.* - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/lmshare/nf-lmshare-netfilegetinfo. Also this won't work for local files. See `openfiles /local /?`

Comment: @Hursey : Thanks for your posting. Additional information's: With FileSystemWatcher, I monitor some drives (local and network) - that works. If the file is on a network location, I want to know (and then store) which user ACTUALLY  has the file open (as with fileinfo.GetOwner(<file>) you only get the OWNER of the file (= user that initially has created the file). I think, it's a problem with the (my) rights, but don't be able to solve it. I have local admin and also have tried with domain admin rights -> always "access denied".

Comment: @Lundt: Thanks for your posting. I learned something new (commands net helpmsg5 and openfiles). It seems as my domain account has not really administrator rights, although my account (which I use for login) is showed in windows with the additional text "Administrator" and I'm able to start an app with "start as administrator". I have tried "openfiles / local" to see how it is set actually and get the message, that my account don't have admin rights. Started a cmd "as admin" and it showed, that the option is off. So... how to give my account "real" admin-rights?

Comment: Local administrators have power over the local computer. They have no special powers on the domain. So the answer is talk to the network administrator. NB Backup operators can call it and your network admin is more likely to grant that.

Comment: @Lundt: Thanks for your feedback. I AM the network administrator and gave my account already domain admin rights and now Backup operators in advance. Still the same. I'm short before to give up :-(

Answer (score 0):

**First, thanks to all that have posted messages here.**

**The good news:**
**My posted code works…**

**The bad news:**
It’s a (heavy) problem with the rights.
The only way, I get it to work was, to run the app **directly on the fileserver with admin rights** (login on the server with Administrator).
I had local admin rights on my client and my account was in the workstation admin group (of the domain), added groups "domain admin" and "administrator" to my account… don’t work.
Logged in as (local) administrator… don’t work.
Tried also unc path (instead of the logical drive)… don’t work.

So… the purpose of the app was, to let the user:

- config some drives (and directories) to monitor with FileSystemWatcher()
- select the datatypes to monitor (e.g. .docx, .xlsx)
- get and store all accesses to the files
- if the file is stored on a server - get the username of the user that has stored the file as last with NetFileEnum() - and store also the user name to the data
- let the user set a filter to only his own files (for network drives)

**So… unfortunately - for me (my app) is NetFileEnum() simply not usable.**